# Twilio voice transcribing replacement

Tags: c#, sms, voice-recognition, twilio

I'm looking to use [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) to

1. Receive a call
2. Transcribe the voice
3. Text the user back with the transcribed recording

I've got this nicely setup but the transcribing on Twilio is of a bizarrely low quality. It could be that it can't understand my Yorkshire accent (it's a Califorian company after all) but there are [complaints from others](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/why_is_transcription_so_inaccurate_even_if_i_have_the_caller_spell_the_word_s?from_gsfn=true) with presumably clearer speaking voices that it is truly awful.

I have an idea that I could swap out their own transcription service and use a third party. I reckon I can grab the mp3 file that is generates. So what i need is

1. A third party transcription service callable via a webservice or similar
2. The service generates a callback when done
3. The service consumes mp3 files
4. The service actually transcribes reasonably. It doesn't need to be perfect as the text will go back to the user for correction but it does need to be fairly good.

Does anyone have experience of such a thing? I'm not committed to Twilio - I'm still at proof of concept so a complete alternative would be of interest as well.

Does that seem like a reasonable thing. Have I gone mad event trying it? Thanks for all response.

Just for completeness - I'm using an MVC 3 architecture with a Razor engine but I don't think that's hugely relevant.

Many Thanks

Comment: mp3 is a bad decision here. Lossy mp3 compression significantly corrupts speech and reduces ASR accuracy. Lossless codec like flac is better.

Comment: And there could be other reasons for reduced accuracy which have to be analyzed

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [programmers.se]

Comment: @MattEllen Thanks for that. TBH I'm surprised about the close votes. From the FAQ - i believe that this question covers 3 out of the 4 requirements for SO i.e. a specific programming problem, software tools commonly used by programmers, practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession. It doesn't have source code though but that's only a preference. I'm seeing Programmers as more general than this - but happy to reask there if this gets closed which now looks likely

Comment: @CrabBucket I'm with you, I see no reason why this shouldn't be on SO.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev He can get the audio from Twilio as mp3 or wav.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the two (the only that I know of) APIs that offer transcription. Both offer machine and human transcription, depending on your needs:

[VoiceCloud](http://www.voicecloud.com/features/api/): You post a link to the audio file (mp3/wav) and they'll send the text to a callback URL when processed. Transcription is $0.10/minute for machine transcription, $0.009/sec for human assisted. I believe the $250.00 monthly minimum only applies to the human transcription.

[QuickTate](http://quicktate.com/quicktate/api.php): You submit an audio file or link via XML-RPC, and QuickTate will send the finished transcription via a callback URL. You can also check job status to get a partial transcription. Price depends on prepay and they offer medical quality as well. It's from around $0.01 to $0.025 per word.

I've used both, and my recommendation would be QuickTate if you need quality transcriptions (although VoiceCloud will still beat the quality of Twilio's native transcription). If you have many short files Quicktate will likely be lower cost, as VoiceCloud (when I used it) had a minimum charge of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Voice!**

Sending the mp3 would be slightly tricky because you would have to play it in real-time, but google voice automatically transcribes voicesmails and I have not personally heard any negative reviews of their transcription.

I just recently did a review for my company of VoIP and Voicemail solutions, and Google Voice was a big part of it.  If there were any serious problems with their transcription, I probably would have stumbled upon them in my search.

You can also set up a Google Voice Lite account that is just voicemail and not any kind of phone extras.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is there some kind of API for the service?I've looked and I can't see one.

Comment: That is the tricky part.  It looks like someone developed a C# API: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/ (but I just found that and can not speak on its efficacy)

Comment: If this were my project, I would probably call the GV number, leave a message, and then set up some kind of parser that accesses the google voice transcription just like a human would, and then send that message wherever it needed to go.  Google Voice will send you an email reminder when you have a voicemail that could be used as a trigger.